# Searching for scenarios in list with incomplete name in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list in which I have stored the value of several simulations. This list consists of 4 columns: date, model, scenario and value.

For each model there are 3*500 scenarios. And each date, every model (10) are simulated.

There are 3 groups of scenarios of 500 elements each. And they are coded with some letters and some numbers. Let's supose that they are grouped as follows:

Scenary_1,Scenary_1,Scenary_2.....Scenary_499 Scenary_Stressed_0,Scenary_Stressed_1,Scenary_Stressed_2...Scenary_Stressed_499 Scenary_Normal_0,Scenary_Normal_1,Scenary_Normal_2...Scenary_Normal_499

Is there any way in which I can select all the Stressed Scenarios in a certain date for a certain model?

I have tried several options like this but I don't get the result:

```
result<-data[which(data$model=="model1" & data$date==20150101 & data$scenario=="Scenary_Stressed"*),]
```

Note: I can obtain all scenarios with:

```
result<-data[which(data$model=="model1" & data$date==20150101),]
```

but is not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grepl` to find all rows with "Stressed" in `Scenario` column.

```
data[grepl("Stressed", data$model), ]
```

You can add other logical checks

```
data[grepl("Stressed", data$model) & data$model == "model1", ]
```